# How can I display a Group Membership in custom user profile

Tags: organic-groups, users

I would like to display the group of a member in their user profile but I don't know the PHP syntax for getting the group.  I'm using the render function, but I have an error.  When I put `print_r($user_profile);`, I get the following array structure :

```
Array
(
    [#printed] => 1
    [user_picture] => Array
        (
            [#markup] => 
            [#weight] => -10
            [#type] => markup
            [#pre_render] => Array
                (
                    [0] => drupal_pre_render_markup
                    [1] => ctools_dependent_pre_render
                )
        [#children] => 
        [#printed] => 1
    )

[og_user_group_ref] => Array
    (
        [#theme] => field
        [#weight] => 0
        [#title] => Group membership
        [#access] => 1
        [#label_display] => above
        [#view_mode] => full
        [#language] => und
        [#field_name] => og_user_group_ref
        [#field_type] => entityreference
        [#field_translatable] => 0
        [#entity_type] => user
        [#bundle] => user
        [#object] => stdClass Object
            (
                [uid] => 11
                [name] => tmeddeb
                [pass] => $S$DRJpiD/FKXsAIoBKMv9YFcGMfhu/4jU0TfOaoeolVcS4ZhxP8KIA
                [mail] => tmeddeb@ccomptes.net
                [theme] => 
                [signature] => 
                [signature_format] => filtered_html
                [created] => 1348668493
                [access] => 1349771256
                [login] => 1349771256
                [status] => 1
                [timezone] => Europe/Berlin
                [language] => ar
                [picture] => 
                [init] => tmeddeb@ccomptes.net
                [data] => 
                [roles] => Array
                    (
                        [2] => authenticated user
                        [8] => الناشر
                        [10] => _user_role_11
                    )

                [og_user_group_ref] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [target_id] => 17
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [og_other_user_group_ref] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [field_grade] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => مستشار لدائرة المحاسبات
                                        [format] => 
                                        [safe_value] => مستشار لدائرة المحاسبات
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [field_function] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => مدير عام
                                        [format] => 
                                        [safe_value] => مدير عام
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [field_firstname] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => الطاهر
                                        [format] => 
                                        [safe_value] => الطاهر
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [field_lastname] => Array
                    (
                        [und] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => المؤدّب
                                        [format] => 
                                        [safe_value] => المؤدّب
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [rdf_mapping] => Array
                    (
                        [rdftype] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => sioc:UserAccount
                            )

                        [name] => Array
                            (
                                [predicates] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => foaf:name
                                    )

                            )

                        [homepage] => Array
                            (
                                [predicates] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => foaf:page
                                    )

                                [type] => rel
                            )

                    )

                [realname] => tmeddeb
                [entity_view_prepared] => 1
                [privatemsg_disabled] => 
            )

        [#items] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [target_id] => 17
                    )

            )

        ***[#formatter] => og_list_default
        [0] => Array
            (
                [#type] => link
                [#title] => غرفة الموارد البشرية
                [#href] => http://localhost/drupal/?q=node/17
            )***

        [#markup] => 
        [#children] => <div class="field field-name-og-user-group-ref field-type-entityreference field-label-above"><div class="field-label">Group membership:&nbsp;</div><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><a href="http://localhost/drupal/?q=node/17">غرفة الموارد البشرية</a></div></div></div>
        [#printed] => 1
    )
```

But when I try to get the title value of [formatter] I get the following fatal error:

**Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in C:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\themes\courdescomptes\user-profile.tpl.php on line 17**

The function for getting a title value for formatter is as follows:

```
print render($user_profile['og_user_group_ref']['#formatter'][0]['title'])
```

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your output it should be `#title` not `title`:

```
print render($user_profile['og_user_group_ref']['#formatter'][0]['#title']);
```

Since `#title` is a string though you'll want to just print it directly and save yourself the tiny bit of overhead:

```
print $user_profile['og_user_group_ref']['#formatter'][0]['#title'];
```

Comment: whene I put your code print $user_profile['og_user_group_ref']['#formatter'][0]['#title'];
I have alse the same problem     Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in C:\wamp\www\drupal\sites\all\themes\courdescomptes\user-profile.tpl.php on line 17